# Best php static code analyzer for eclipse?

Tags: php, code-analysis, eclipse, code-review

Can someone recommend me the best and easy static code analyzer or plugin used for code review for php in eclipse?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but *best* and *easy* are opinion based. Please [read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [edit] your question.

Comment: Can you give us a list of requirements?

Comment: like findBugs do for Java, i need to know if there is any tool for PHP.

My aim to get the issues or vulnerabilities in the code and do a proper security audit and reduce the bugs